# How to launch a Thread inside a BackgroundWorker?

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

My application has to connect to an API and download around 1200 items. Because how the API works, I can't ask for all the items at once, I have to send one query for each item. Items are small, so the downloads are quick, and the server blocks me (for 4-5 seconds) if I send too many requests in a short amount of time (100 requests per 2-3 seconds). I don't want the server blocking my app around 10-12 times each time, so I decided to implement a slowdown on purpose, another thread that simply sleeps for 0.4 seconds, and the worker will join it, so if the worker finishes each download before the 0.4s mark it will wait, and if it finishes latter, it will proceed directly to the next

**Desired implementation:**

```
private void DownloadLibrary_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    int max = 1200;
    int slowdown = 400; // milliseconds

    Thread methronome = new Thread(() => Thread.Sleep(slowdown));

    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
    {
        methronome.Start();

        DownloadItem(i);            
        WorkerDownloadLibrary.ReportProgress((int)i / max, string.Format("Dowloaded item {0} out of {1}", i+1, max));

        methronome.Join();
    }
}

private void UserClickStart(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Let's start!");
    WorkerDownloadLibrary.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void DownloadLibrary_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{ 
    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Completed!"); 
}
```

The problem is that, if I do this, the background worker ends prematurely (RunWorkerCompleted executes), and if I comment both the `methronome.Start()` and `methronome.Join()` lines, it do the work as intended, but of course ends up being blocked from time to time. **What I'm doing wrong?**

---

I can implement the wait directly on the backgroundworker because the downloads are fast enough anyway, but still seems bad designed, and it will slow it too much on a slow computer.

**Working but slow implementation:**

```
private void DownloadLibrary_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    int max = 1200;
    int slowdown = 400; // milliseconds

    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
    {
        DownloadItem(i);            
        WorkerDownloadLibrary.ReportProgress((int)i / max, string.Format("Dowloaded item {0} out of {1}", i+1, max));
        Thread.Sleep(slowdown);
    }
}
```

---

There is another way to do it: Send all the queries one after the other, and wait only when the server blocks, but seems very bad by design, and the user will scratch its head when the download stops each 2 seconds. And the server may block me permanently if I do this always

**Working but plain bad implementation**

```
private void DownloadLibrary_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    int max = 1200;
    int slowdown = 5000; // milliseconds

    string serverResponse;
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
    {
        do
        {
            serverResponse = DownloadItem(i);

            if (serverResponse != "OK")
                Thread.Sleep(slowdown);

        } while (serverResponse != "OK") ;

        WorkerDownloadLibrary.ReportProgress((int)i / max, string.Format("Dowloaded item {0} out of {1}", i+1, max));
    }
}
```

How can I implement the first option?

Comment: Have you tried to use a Stopwatch to time the execution of your download and then wait for the remaining milliseconds? It would be the improved version of your **Working but slow implementation**. Using an additional thread to do the timing seems overkill to me.

Comment: You could also try to get the data provider to offer a bulk query option, would probably make them happier as well, if you're going to query them often.

Comment: @BartoszKP It is not intended to be fast. I explained on the question: the API server blocks me if the app goes too fast. This way the user can see a "smooth" download, even if it goes slow.
@jessehouwing Good idea! I'll try the `Stopwatch`. About asking the data provider, well they don't care too much about the API, the documentation is awful and I asked for technical questions in the past but their responses are always vague and not useful. I can assure you they will not put resources on improving their API. Maybe in the future when my app is finished I'll ask them about the "bulk" option

Comment: Which .NET framework version are you using?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov 4.5, still gonna try jesse's solution and will post the results here

Comment: The resolution of Thread.Sleep() is fairly crude, the minimum time you can sleep is 15.625 msec and effective sleep durations are an integer multiple of that.  Do consider the alternative, asking for, say, 99 data items in a row and then sleeping for 3 seconds or sleeping 30 msec in between them.  Which is a happy number, 100 items x 31.25 msec = 3.125 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach doesn't work because, [as the documentation explains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x4c42hc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Once the thread terminates, it cannot be restarted with another call to Start.

So, the simplest fix is to recreate the thread each time:

```
for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
{
    Thread methronome = new Thread(() => Thread.Sleep(slowdown));
    methronome.Start();

   //..
```

However, it is unclear why would you want to do it. The code runs in another thread already, so your second approach, using `Thread.Sleep` seems fine. You could improve it by measuring if you really need to wait the whole amount of time (perhaps some downloading last a little longer so there is no need to always wait all 400 ms). A convenient class that can be used to measure chunks of time (and unlike threads, can be "restarted") is the [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. The idea (posted also by [jessehouwing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/736079/jessehouwing) in the comments) would look something like:

```
int max = 1200;
int slowdownMs = 400;
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

for (int i = 0;i < max; ++i)
{
    sw.Restart();

    DownloadItem(i);    
    ReportProgress(i, max);        

    sw.Stop();

    Thread.Sleep(Math.Max(0, (int)(slowdownMs - sw.ElapsedMilliseconds)));
}

//....
```

Comment: That's indeed what I meant with my comment to sleep the remainder of the 400ms. :). Though I suspect you'll need to explicitly cast `sw.ElapsedMilliseconds` to int, since it's a long and `Thread.Sleep` doesn't take a long.